# grails 2.4.4 console returns ≫ Server returned an error

Tags: grails, console

After upgrading to grails 2.4.4. and console to 1.5.4, grails console starts up fine, but any command I run returns

```
≫ Server returned an error.
```

screenShot -> http://spireon.d.pr/17o8M

No errors, just dies like that.

Comment: If it's a server problem, maybe you should check the grails bugtracker and try to find your server's logs.

Comment: server logs are clean. Nothing there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem seems to be in Config.groovy. Add these lines to Config.groovy and console should work again.

```
grails.plugin.console.baseUrl="/console"
grails.plugin.console.enabled = true
```

Comment: I had to add the context of my application as a prefix, so it's "/my-grails-app/console" for me

Answer (score 2):

Another problem could be that the console is trying to access the application at a different URL/host name, and getting a Cross-site Scripting error.

You can confirm this by checking the web-console to see if something like the following is present:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://phsicalAppAddress/AppName/console/execute. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).
```

If this is happening, it is likely that you're accessing your application from a different URL, and grails needs to know what this is so that the same origin can be applied to the console AJAX request.
This can be set with `grails.serverURL="http://browserURL/AppName"` in Config.groovy